# call of overloaded isnan(double&) is ambiguous

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to compile shapeit - https://github.com/odelaneau/shapeit4
The most recent gcc I have available is 5.3.1
When I run make, the following error trace is shown:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -mavx2 -mfma  -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o -Isrc -I/local/src/htslib-1.3.2/htslib -I/local/include/boost
In file included from src/phaser/phaser_header.h:29:0,
             from src/main.cpp:23:
src/models/haplotype_segment_single.h: In member function ‘bool 
haplotype_segment_single::TRANS_DIP_MULT()’:
src/models/haplotype_segment_single.h:556:25: error: call of overloaded ‘isnan(double&)’ is ambiguous
  return (isnan(sumDProbs) || isinf(sumDProbs) || sumDProbs < numeric_limits<double>::min());
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:375:0,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/c++config.h:2255,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algobase.h:59,
                 from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/vector:60,
                 from src/utils/otools.h:26,
                 from src/phaser/phaser_header.h:27,
                 from src/main.cpp:23:
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h:235:1: note: candidate: int isnan(double)
__MATHDECL_1 (int,isnan,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
 ^
In file included from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/random:38:0,
             from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
             from /opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/algorithm:62,
             from src/utils/otools.h:35,
             from src/phaser/phaser_header.h:27,
             from src/main.cpp:23:
/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/cmath:634:3: note: candidate: constexpr bool std::isnan(long double)
   isnan(long double __x)
   ^
/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/cmath:630:3: note: candidate: constexpr bool std::isnan(double)
   isnan(double __x)
   ^
/opt/rh/devtoolset-4/root/usr/include/c++/5.3.1/cmath:626:3: note: candidate: constexpr bool std::isnan(float)
   isnan(float __x)
   ^
In file included from src/phaser/phaser_header.h:29:0,
                 from src/main.cpp:23:
```

I attempted to replace the `isnan(sumDProbs)` call with `std::isnan(sumDProbs)` or with `::isnan(sumDProbs)`.  Both of these finished compiling, but the resulting binary threw an Illegal Instruction.  Is there a different namespace I should be using to clarify the `isnan` call?

This is el7 with the devtoolset-4 activated because el7 has gcc 4.8.5. I activate using scl enable devtoolset-4 -- bash and then run the compile commands.

I do not have a `using namespace std;` included.

This is the line that's throwing the ambiguous error:
https://github.com/odelaneau/shapeit4/blob/master/src/models/haplotype_segment_single.h#L556

```
bool haplotype_segment_single::TRANS_HAP() {
sumHProbs = 0.0f;
unsigned int  curr_rel_segment_index = curr_segment_index-segment_first;
yt = M.getForwardTransProb(AlphaLocus[curr_rel_segment_index - 1], curr_abs_locus);
nt = 1.0f - yt;
//float fact1 = M.nt[curr_abs_locus-1] / AlphaSumSum[curr_rel_segment_index - 1];
float fact1 = nt / AlphaSumSum[curr_rel_segment_index - 1];
fill_n(HProbs, HAP_NUMBER*HAP_NUMBER, 0.0f);
for (int h1 = 0 ; h1 < HAP_NUMBER ; h1++) {
    //float fact2 = (AlphaSum[curr_rel_segment_index-1][h1]/AlphaSumSum[curr_rel_segment_index-1]) * M.t[curr_abs_locus - 1] / n_cond_haps;
    float fact2 = (AlphaSum[curr_rel_segment_index-1][h1]/AlphaSumSum[curr_rel_segment_index-1]) * yt / n_cond_haps;
    for (int k = 0 ; k < n_cond_haps ; k ++) {
        for (int h2 = 0 ; h2 < HAP_NUMBER ; h2++) HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+h2]+=((Alpha[curr_rel_segment_index-1][k*HAP_NUMBER + h1]*fact1 + fact2)*prob[k*HAP_NUMBER+h2]);
    }
    sumHProbs += HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+0]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+1]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+2]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+3]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+4]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+5]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+6]+HProbs[h1*HAP_NUMBER+7];
}
return (isnan(sumHProbs) || isinf(sumHProbs) || sumHProbs < numeric_limits<float>::min());
}
```

Do I need to change this line:
`return (isnan(sumHProbs) || isinf(sumHProbs) || sumHProbs < numeric_limits<float>::min());`

to
`return (isnan((double)sumHProbs) || isinf(sumHProbs) || sumHProbs < numeric_limits<float>::min());`

Comment: What architecture are you running the program on?  I notice you're specifying AVX2.  If the compiler is vectorizing `isnan` into AVX instructions, and your architecture doesn't support it, that would explain the illegal instruction.  You should use your favorite debugger to determine exactly what instruction is throwing this error.

Comment: @DeniseMauldin What paddy says is most probably is the reason. But since the error is about ambiguous call, did you try explicitly typecasting to double for example (I am unable to determine whether it's your code). If it is your code which is calling isnan, could you give us minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Do you have a `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @paddy This is el7 with the devtoolset-4 activated because el7 has gcc 4.8.5. I activate using `scl enable devtoolset-4 -- bash` and then run the compile commands.

Comment: @vish I added the function from shapeit that's throwing the ambiguous error

Comment: It looks like there is a `using namespace std` or `using std::isnan` hidden somewhere, and your version of devtoolset is slightly incompatible with your version of rhel. You copied the wrong code, the error is about sumDProbs, not sumHProbs. Your workaround with std:: makes sense and is unlikely to be the cause of the crash.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yeah, I'm suspicious because it has a isnan from /usr/include/bits/mathcalls.h as a candidate that there is a hidden `using namespace std` somewhere.  There's errors both with sumDProbs and sumHProbs that are the same.  Both are defined as double at the top of the file rather than inside the functions since they're supposed to be globals.